# How to call functions in a component from other components in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I am developing a web app in Angular.

I have a problem that there is a component called `editor-component` and it contains some functions to manipulate an editor (for example, `getValue()`). While in other components I also need to call the functions in `editor-component`, the relationship between components is not parent/child, and I am using modals in `ngx-bootstrap`.

So my problem is is there any way I can let all other components use the functions in `editor-component`?

Comment: Since it's not a parent/child relationship you need to use a shared service to communicate between your components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally I got a solution.

It's somehow similar to the existing ones, using shared service with two fields.

In the `editorService`, set an `getContentEvent` and register the event both in `editorComponent` and `otherComponent`, set a field `content : string`. When the event emits, in `editorComponent` subscribe the event and  set the `content` filed in service, thus other components can get the `content`.

Answer (score 1):

try to use service for storing functions from editor-component.
modals are a little harder. code from bootstrap demo:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showModal()">Open a modal</button>
<pre *ngFor="let message of messages">{{message}}</pre>

<div class="modal fade" bsModal #modal="bs-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
     (onShow)="handler('onShow', $event)"
     (onShown)="handler('onShown', $event)"
     (onHide)="handler('onHide', $event)"
     (onHidden)="handler('onHidden', $event)">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Just another modal <br>
        Click <b>&times;</b>, press <code>Esc</code> or click on backdrop to close modal.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this modal is inside component scope. and with this #modal="bs-modal" we can use context of modal by using variable "modal"
more info http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a little different, I am using `ngx-bootstrap`, the modal is therefore an entry component, toggled by a service.